# Direct Download for Latest Version of Aptana Studio

Tags: aptana, aptana3

Does an API exist for getting a direct download to the latest version of Aptana for an arbitrary architecture and OS?

I've been looking over the Aptana download page, and it looks like they used a bit of javascript to detect the settings of the OS, and then instead of doing a get request, they do a post of the data.  A GET URL would be much easier to use.  Does such an API exist at Aptana, like maybe `download.aptana.com/latest_stable?os=linux&arch=64&standalone=false`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like they are serving their downloads via Amazon's Cloudfront CDN.  Without knowing the actual origin of the file, which I'm sure they don't want you knowing, you can't really do much.

With that said, here is the actual URL for the Linux 64-bit version.  You could do some guessing with this URL string and figure out how to build the URL for future releases, provided the adhere to the same convention.

`http://download.aptana.com/studio3/standalone/3.4.0/linux/Aptana_Studio_3_Setup‌​_Linux_x86_64_3.4.0.zip`

Comment: This url leads to the one you posted above.  `http://download.aptana.com/studio3/standalone/3.4.0/linux/Aptana_Studio_3_Setup_Linux_x86_64_3.4.0.zip` It looks like yours has a build number in there, which is a lot of work for guessing.

Answer (score 1):

A little late, but...

Here is the link for all the older Aptana Studio versions:

https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Reverting+to+a+Previous+Version

3.4.2 is not yet on that list. The link (for Windows) is the following:

http://d1iwq2e2xrohf.cloudfront.net/tools/studio/standalone/3.4.2.201308081805/win/Aptana_Studio_3_Setup_3.4.2.exe