# Aptana 3 Standalone zip file

Tags: zip, aptana, installation-package

Where can I find the latest standalone version of Aptana 3 in .zip?

Ive read this post [Direct Download for Latest Version of Aptana Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380518/direct-download-for-latest-version-of-aptana-studio/16380579#16380579) but that url return "The page you are looking for is temporarily unavailable. Please try again later.".

Is there any way to download windows zip?

Answer (score 1):

You have you replace the version number for specific version on download url:

Here is for windows:
http://download.aptana.com/studio3/standalone/3.4.2/win/Aptana_Studio_3_Setup_Win_3.4.2.zip

For Linux:

Url below is correct format, but not downloadable, it seems goes 403 access deny.
http://download.aptana.com/studio3/standalone/3.4.2/linux/Aptana_Studio_3_Setup_Linux_x86_x64_3.4.2.zip

Answer (score 0):

The link in the previous answer does not work anymore.

Here is the link for all the older Aptana Studio versions:

https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Reverting+to+a+Previous+Version

3.4.2 is not yet on that list. The link (for Windows) is the following:

http://d1iwq2e2xrohf.cloudfront.net/tools/studio/standalone/3.4.2.201308081805/win/Aptana_Studio_3_Setup_3.4.2.exe